# How to uniquely identify visitors with IP addres plus some other identifier?

Tags: javascript, php, security, ip

I am making a site where I want users to be able to vote on things without having to make an account, and I would like to restrict voting to be once per visitor. I would like to use IP address, but I understand this is not unique to users, for instance a whole college campus can share one IP

Are there any pre-built Javascript tools or libraries that can give me info about the persons computer  that will in combination with the IP address be enough to identify them uniquely?

Ideally it would be something that would work even if they switched browsers/cleared cookies (I doubt cookies will matter as I would be putting this IP/session info into a database)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `cookies` & the `IP address` to detect an old user but both can be changed.

User can delete the cookies from his browser & also change the IP address since most of the users use dynamic IP address.

If only logged in users voting is possible, the use that!